# How to assign static IP to KVM VM after bridging?

Tags: 14.04, virtualization, kvm-virtualization, network-bridge

I created a bridge using the following guide on my Ubuntu 14.04 server.

> http://www.linux-kvm.org/page/Networking#Public_Bridge

Now I would like to assign a static public IP to my virtual machine. How do I do it?

Comment: A static ***public*** IP? Ummmm.... you'd have to contact your ISP and ask them to give you a static IP.

Comment: If you meant a static *local* IP, then that's a different story.

Comment: Hey @AndroidDev. I have a static IP which is already leased and ready to be used. I tried manually configuring in the /etc/network/interfaces file. But it doesn't work.

Comment: see step 3 [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/638162/kvm-network-bridge-to-assign-static-ip/638269#638269)

Comment: Hey @DougSmythies. I tried the same thing earlier. It doesn't seem to work. Thank you

Comment: Yes, I was writing, and didn't see your comment until after. Read the rest of the link I gave, any help with that? Specifically, did you tell your VM to use the bridge? (Step 2).

Comment: @DougSmythies I followed the step 2 also. But do I need to change the mac address as well? The br0 in my case has a different HWaddr when checked in ifconfig.

Comment: Yes, of course. You need to use your own VM's MAC address, what I listed was just an example taken from one of my VM's. This part has nothing to do with the MAC address of the bridge.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/45160/discussion-between-mohit-vellanki-and-doug-smythies).

Answer (score 0):

Editors there is a different question, but fundamentally the same problem I answered here. New to this so not sure if/how to merge - [Ping to LXC container](https://askubuntu.com/questions/598395/ping-to-lxc-container/890741#890741)

In addition to the bridge, you need ensure you have a dedicated virtual network card on the Linux Container which will then be assigned the IP address on your hosts machine's network.

Below are the core instructions, but [detailed steps and background come from this Bonsai Framework article](http://www.bonsaiframework.com/wiki/display/bonsai/5.1+LXC+Advanced+Networking+-+Exposing+Containers+to+the+Network#id-5.1LXCAdvancedNetworking-ExposingContainerstotheNetwork-macvlanwithAdditionalIP).

> ### Create a Permanent macvlan on the Host
>
> Add to the bottom of the `/etc/network/interfaces` file of the host,
>
> ```
> # Creates a macvlan interface called macvlan0 without an IP address  
> iface mvlan0 inet manual  
>    pre-up ip link add mvlan0 link eth0 address 8a:38:2a:cc:d7:aa type macvlan mode bridge  
>    post-down ip link del macvlan0  
> auto mvlan0
> ```

Reboot your system to have the change take effect. You will notice a `mvlan0` now when viewing your network devices with `ifconfig -a`.

Connect Container to `macvlan` on Host by modifying the config file located in `/var/lib/lxc/[container]/config`.

> The entries to add for your new network card,
>
> ```
> # macvlan for external IP  
> lxc.network.type = macvlan   
> lxc.network.macvlan.mode = bridge  
> lxc.network.flags = up  
> lxc.network.link = mvlan0  
> lxc.network.hwaddr = 00:16:3e:8d:4f:51  
> lxc.network.name = eth0
> ```

For the hwaddr, generate a unique locally administered unicast MAC Address via a free website like [helion.org](https://www.hellion.org.uk/cgi-bin/randmac.pl).

Finally, adjust the interfaces file within the container to bind via static or if you prefer use dynamic.

In my case, I adjust my home router so that 192.168.0.1 to 192.168.0.20 are not dynamically assigned and use static in my LXC.

So I modify my containers interfaces file as follows,

```
auto eth0  
iface eth0 inet static  
address 192.168.0.12  
gateway 192.168.0.1  
netmask 255.255.255.0  

auto eth1  
iface eth1 inet dhcp
```

Restart your Linux container.